# Floating Main Menu To Right of Site Name

Tags: html, css

Hello i seem to be having a little trouble doing the simplest of tasks tonight. Trying to make my primary-menu float to the right of [my site](http://onlinebanter.com/) site-name.

```
<header>
  <div id="header">
    <div class="g3">
      <h1 id="site-name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cf"></div>
</header>
<nav>
  <div id="primary-menu" class="g3 nav">
    <ul id="main-menu" class="menu links clearfix">
  </div>
</nav>
 <div class="cf"></div>
```

I dont know if i should be pasting in CSS code to help ut there seems too much from what i can gather. Your welcome to pop in and have a look. dont mind the mess.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add this style to header tag:**

```
header {
 width: 110px;
 float: left;
}
```

**and this to your nav:**

```
nav {
 float: left;
 width: 800px;
 margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alpha. I should have mentioned that i am using a responsive theme and im avoiding fixed widths I presume that i just need to chage the code to % though. Ill go give a try and report back in a sec. thanks

Comment: Brilliant Alpha thanks does the trick for me :) i used header {
  display: block
width: 25%;
 float: left;
}

nav {
 float: left;
 width: 75%x;
 margin: 1em;
}

Comment: Actually Alpha i dont know if it's all fixed though. I just looked on Chrome  and the menu is very small http://onlinebanter.com/ Ive cleared caches etc. Seems ok on Firefox. On a seperate note can you see how i make that pink box the same height as the site name? I have been trying . Thanks

Comment: I see a pink box only in firefox. and in chrome menu is not on right of the logo.

Comment: @RegGordon I can not see your css changes in chrome. When i view source of the css file the changed you made are not there. :/

Comment: sorry Alpha i was trying something and then had to run out. Left the bloody default theme on. Im having a bit of a crisis here but i will come back to it soon. the right theme is back on and im sorry